# align and image and text next to each other in 2 column unordered list

Tags: html, css

I am trying to render a 2 column unordered list. I want each li tag to have a image followed by text with a certain gap in between. If the text spills over two lines, the 2nd line must align with the first line, not with the image. I got a solution earlier but, I am told to have a slimmer code.

I need the image to be the background image for each li tag. Code is my teh JSfiddle link.

I am not sure where I am going wrong.

```
<section class="freedom_carousel"> 




<ul class="two-col">
<li class="pen"> <span class="icon-text"> <em>THis is </em> text text text text text text text </span> </li>
<li class="phone"> <span class="icon-text"> <em>THis is </em> text text text text text text text </span> </li>
<li class="arrow"> <span class="icon-text"> <em>THis is </em> text text text text text text text </span> </li>
<li class="download"> <span class="icon-text"> <em>THis is </em> text text text text text text text </span> </li>
</ul>

 </section>
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rwcbdk38/1/

Comment: What size should the background image be?  At best, you could do without the `span` tag, but you won't get much simpler code than that.

Comment: The image that I have is really small. I'd ballpark it around 10px*10px.   

The final result I am looking for is like this http://i.imgur.com/qReaDlP.jpg

PS: My apologies if I didn't explain better earlier. My earlier solution was much longer. I can have the span. But, now, I am able to figure out the way to render it the way I need.

Comment: The problem is that list items are displayed in one column instead of two? That is because 30px padding adds up to 45% *content* width, resulting in overall width more than 50%. Try adding `box-sizing:border-box` to make paddings subtract from the width instead of increasing it.

Comment: The problem is that the background image doesn't show up. It is pointing to the right path becuase when I put it in img tag it shows up.

It stacking in one column is an issue, but I realized it was spacing issue that was fixable.

Answer (score 0):

how if put `<table>` in each `li` ?

```
<table>
            <tr>
                <td class="icon-text"><em>THis is </em></td>
                <td><span >  text text text text text text text </span> </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

LET'S [SEE FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rwcbdk38/2/)